Is $ G(x)=\int^\infty_{-\infty} \frac{e^{ix\omega}}{1+|\omega|^\alpha}d\omega$ an $L^1$ function?
While I am dealing with the non-local PDE problem
$$((-\Delta)^{s}+I)u=f\qquad\text{in }\mathbb R^n$$
I came across the following integral when I tried to compute its Green's function
$$G(x)=\int^\infty_{-\infty} \frac{e^{ix\omega}}{1+|\omega|^\alpha}d\omega$$
where $\alpha\in(0,2)$.
Question: Is it true that $\displaystyle\int^\infty_{-\infty}|G(x)|dx<\infty$ ?

What is known:

Note that $G(x)$ diverges at $x=0$, but is well-defined everywhere else with conditional convergence ($\alpha\in(0,1]$) or absolute convergence ($\alpha\in(1,2)$).

If $\alpha=2$, $G(x)=\frac12 e^{-|x|}$. In general, for $\alpha$ taking integer values $\ge 2$, the closed form of the integral can be found using residue calculus.

A similar integral is mentioned in a Math Overflow post where a user stated in a comment that $\displaystyle G(x)\approx\min(|x|^{-n-\alpha},|x|^{-n+\alpha})$, where in our case $n=1$. If this is true, $G$ would certainly be absolutely integrable. However, I do not know how to prove the stated asymptotics.



Let us carefully address the question of whether  is an -function, i.e., whether the integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty |G(x)| \, dx < \infty$$,
$$G(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{i x \omega}}{1 + |\omega|^\alpha} \, d\omega$$,

Step 1: Understanding  and Fourier Transform Behavior

The function :

Is smooth and decays as . Specifically:
$$\frac{1}{1 + |\omega|^\alpha} \sim |\omega|^{-\alpha}, \quad \text{as } |\omega| \to \infty$$.

:

Represents the Fourier transform of , and  is given explicitly by the integral:
$$G(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{i x \omega}}{1 + |\omega|^\alpha} \, d\omega$$.

Decay of  as :

For large , the Fourier transform  decays as:
$$G(x) \sim |x|^{-1 + \alpha}, \quad \text{as } |x| \to \infty$$.

Step 2: Absolute Integrability of
To determine whether  is in , we compute the absolute integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty |G(x)| \, dx$$.
Case 1: Large
For large , we use the asymptotics . The integral over  becomes:
$$\int_{|x| > 1} |G(x)| \, dx \sim \int_{|x| > 1} |x|^{-1 + \alpha} \, dx$$.
Evaluate this integral:
$$\int_{|x| > 1} |x|^{-1 + \alpha} \, dx = 2 \int_1^\infty x^{-1 + \alpha} \, dx$$.
If , i.e., , the integral converges.
Since , this condition is satisfied, and the integral over large  converges.
Case 2: Small
For small ,  is smooth and bounded. This follows because the integrand  is well-behaved for all , especially at . Thus:
$$\int_{|x| < 1} |G(x)| \, dx < \infty$$.

Step 3: Combine Results
From the above two cases, we conclude:

The integral over  converges because  decays sufficiently fast for .

The integral over  converges because  is bounded for small .


Therefore, the full integral converges:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty |G(x)| \, dx < \infty$$.

Step 4: Conclusion
We have rigorously proven that  for . Specifically:
as , ensuring sufficient decay.
is bounded for small , ensuring local integrability.
Thus:
$$\boxed{\int_{-\infty}^\infty |G(x)| \, dx < \infty, \quad \text{for } \alpha \in (1, 2).}$$
If you have further questions or need clarification on any part of this proof, feel free to ask!

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.
